# Avaya IP Office - "Invalid community specified in SNMP request"

Tags: snmp, avaya

I have an Avaya IP office which is configured to send errors by email. It is normally quiet, however it sometimes decides to send a stack of emails containing:

`Invalid community specified in SNMP request`

I can reproduce by pointing a SNMP client at the PBX with the wrong community string. One would think that there must be a monitoring daemon (e.g. nagios) configured somewhere with the wrong community string, but this is not the case. I have enabled as much debugging as I can on the PBX to try and find out what IP address it is coming from, but so far no luck.

Just wondering if anyone has seen this sort of behaviour on the Avaya IP office before? Or some way to determine what is connecting to it with the wrong SNMP community string?

I am tempted to set up port mirroring on the switch and capture SNMP traffic!

Comment: Sorry I don't have an answer but avayausers.com is the best source I've found for Avaya help.

Comment: You should be able to ask Avaya if there is any logging you can enable to get the IP address when that error occurs again. That can be the fastest way.

Answer (score 2):

Setup port mirroring on the switch and use Wiresharek to determine where the SNMP traffic is coming from. You've got something else on your network querying it by SNMP using an invalid community string.